# Deploy a node.js site using Azure Resource Manager

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-resource-manager

I'm struggling with a ARM deployment script for my node.js application. If I point  to a repo with an MVC application it all works fine, but not using an node.js app.

Are there any specific settings for node.js sites?
Here is the resource part of my script:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
  "name": "[parameters('nodeName')]",
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "tags": {
    "[concat('hidden-related:', resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('nodeName'))]": "Resource",
    "displayName": "Website"
  },
  "dependsOn": [
    "[concat('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/', parameters('nodeName'))]"
  ],
  "resources": [
    {
      "apiVersion": "2015-08-01",
      "name": "web",
      "type": "sourcecontrols",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/Sites', concat(parameters('nodeName')))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "repoUrl": "https://github.com/microServiceBus/microservicebus.node.git",
        "branch": "master",
        "IsManualIntegration": true
      }
    }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": "[parameters('nodeName')]",
    "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', parameters('nodeName'))]",
    "siteConfig": {
      "appSettings": [
        {
          "Name": "hubUri",
          "Value": "[parameters('hubUri')]"
        },
        {
          "Name": "nodeName",
          "Value": "[parameters('nodeName')]"
        },
        {
          "Name": "organizationaId",
          "Value": "[parameters('organizationaId')]"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the error do you encounter? Are you able to add more details on the error?

Comment: Do you mean your application doesn't work after you successfully deploy to Azure? Or you failed to deploy to Azure with this template?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the name of the repo had a dot in it (microservicebus.node.git). I believe the bug is fixed or is going to be fixed soon.